# Cursor doesn't work same with Jellybean?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm working on some code that takes a name and number from a database and displays it. The code works on the emulator running 1.6 but not on my Galaxy Nexus running 4.1.1.

Whenever I call viewEntries() on my device, my app force closes and give an IllegalStateException that the column cannot be found. WhitelistDB extends from SQLiteOpenHelper.

Thank you for any help.

```
public String getData()
{
    WhitelistDB DB = new WhitelistDB(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = DB.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] columns = new String[]{WhitelistDB.KEY_ID, WhitelistDB.KEY_NAME, WhitelistDB.KEY_NUMBER};
    Cursor c = db.query(WhitelistDB.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int count = c.getColumnCount();
    String noEntries = "No entries in whitelist.";

    if(count < 1)
    {
        return noEntries;
    }

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(WhitelistDB.KEY_ID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(WhitelistDB.KEY_NAME);
    int iNumber = c.getColumnIndex(WhitelistDB.KEY_NUMBER);

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
    {
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iNumber) + "\n";
    }

    db.close();

    return result;
}

public void viewEntries()
{
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wlData);
    String info = getData();
    tv.setText(info);
}
```

This is the error I get.

```
07-31 18:42:10.706: E/CursorWindow(10024): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 7 rows, 3 columns.
07-31 18:42:10.706: D/AndroidRuntime(10024): Shutting down VM
07-31 18:42:10.706: W/dalvikvm(10024): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41dbe300)
07-31 18:42:10.714: E/AndroidRuntime(10024): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 18:42:10.714: E/AndroidRuntime(10024): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mutoor.autoreply/com.mutoor.autoreply.WhitelistActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
07-31 18:42:10.714: E/AndroidRuntime(10024):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace as well.

Comment: Have you tried doing a full uninstall of the app on your Nexus? A database is only created once so if you had opened the database with a previous version of that table it will not have any newly added columns.

Comment: Turns it that was all I needed to do. I had deleted just the database directory when I wanted to restart the database. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the previously installed data with:

<kbd>Settings</kbd> --> <kbd>Apps</kbd> --> <kbd>[app name]</kbd> --> <kbd>Clear data</kbd>